# limit td width that has span elements

Tags: html, css

I've the following code:

```
  <td>
    <span class='label label-success'>text1</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text2</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text3</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text4</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text5</span>
  </td>
```

I want to limit the width of the  so I can get line breaks between spans when the max width is reached, something like this:

```
text1 text2 text3
text4 text5
```

Assuming that text4 exceeded the max width.

Ideas?

Comment: Cannot do with CSS ONLY if you want to detect the td elements having span elements as children

Comment: so the only solution is to write a JS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `table-layout:fixed` to the `table` tag in your CSS, then add the width of the `td` that you want, like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <td> 
    <span class='label label-success'>text1</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text2</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text3</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text4</span>
    <span class='label label-success'>text5</span>
  </td>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   table-layout: fixed;
}

table td {
   width: 100px; /* The width you want */
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mNux/1/

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a command like that

```
<td width="200px"> .... </td>
```

will do the trick for you